# How to make a for-loop to finish and only then fire a scrapy function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, scrapy

I have a simple spider class with two functions. One to get the links from the starting page and enter them (also -- to get the next page link), another -- to parse each link (the page it leads to). The problem is that I have a for loop that iterates over links and yields a `scrapy.Request` for each of them and after this for loop I have an `if` statement to check, if the current page is the last one, if not -- I want to yield the first function with next page link, if yes -- to stop the spider and say 'Last page, mate!'.

```
def parse(self, response):

    links = response.xpath('//tags_to_be_chosen/@href').getall()

    next_page = response.xpath('//tag_to_be_chosen/@href').get()

    check = response.xpath('//tag_to_be_chosen/text()').get()

    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link.strip()), callback=self.parse_page)

    if 'specific_string_is' in check: # go to next page, but only after for loop has finished its job
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page.strip()), callback=self.parse)
    else: # stop the crawler, because we've reached the last page
        print('We\'ve reached the last page!')

def parse_page(self, response):

    with open('file_to_write', 'a') as file: # when there's a table of items to be crawled (different tags used than for a single item)
        for item in response.xpath('//tags_to_be_chosen/text()').getall():
            file.write('{}\n'.format(item.strip()))
        else: # when there's a single item to be crawled (different tag used than for multiple items
            item = response.xpath('//tag_to_be_chosen').get()
            item = item.strip()
            item = re.sub('sth_to_be_deleted', '', item)
            file.write('{}\n'.format(item))
```

The expected result is to wait until the for loop finishes invoking function no 2 (entering and parsing all links) and only then enter the next page link. For some reason `if` is being checked while `for` is still looping over links, function to parse next page is being invoked (which means changing the links) and the process starts for new links not finishing the "old" ones.

---

A BIG EDIT DONE, as pointed out in the comments:

Comment: You say “For some reason (maybe it's the way it is) if is being checked while for is still looping over links”. I don’t think that’s possible, unless `parse` is called multiple times, in which case it’s possible that one of the calls is in the `loop` while another has reached already the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you using yield? is this method been iterated externally?  The last IF would be called after the external iteration is done, but looks like you are iterating a local variable `links`. You probably don't need yield there.

It is also not clear if you are trying to do a depth-first by entering a link and then **scraping** the link's links, or a breadth-first, getting every link from the page, then parsing the main page, and move on to the collected links.

For the link **scraping**, you can achieve this in 2 ways, serial or parallel.

- For serial you would just do a for loop calling the request with its callback
- For parallel you would have to have a thread pool, send each link processing to a thread, and after the for loop, join the pool to wait for all threads, and then call you function 2.

Comment: I'm using `yield` because I thought it's the way Scrapy works... . First link is in `start_urls`. `parse` function parses the first link and from its content it scrapes both `next_page` link and all links-to-enter-and-scrape-pages-content-from (it's `link for links`). Then there's this check, if `next_page` link was scraped: if yes -- it should re-call `parse` function with the new link (or maybe `parse` function is intended only for `start_urls`?) after the loop finishes. If not -- end the process. For some reason this `if` isn't called after, but parallel to it. Is it because of the `yield`?

Comment: yes, the yield will turn your method into a generator, so the for loop will advance as the outer function that is calling your function calls `next`.  Once the iteration is done, it will continue with the code from `if not condition`. You should provide the full example though so its easier to understand. the entire function 1 and 2 and the caller of those functions.

Comment: I've added a big edit to my question. Maybe now it will be more clear, sorry about that inconvenience.

Comment: parse_page will be called while looping, because you are defining it as a callback for the Request object. So:
Some one iterates `parse`, for each iteration a Request is create which will call parse_page. Once the iteration is done, the final lines of parse will be called, which they create another Request object with a callback to parse_page as well.  Since the parse_page is called concurrently you have to make sure is thread safe

Comment: As far as I understand Scrapy, `parse` will start with the link or links in `start_urls=[]`. In my case that's a single link. First 3 `response.xpath` assignments refer to that link. Then I'm looping and invoking `parse_page`. But after that loop I'm not invoking `parse_page`. I'm invoking `parse`, assuming the `if` condition is met. Anyway, how do I make `parse_page` thread safe?

Comment: I think I'll just split the job into 2 spiders: 1 to scrape all links (page by page), another one -- to scrape content inside them... I'm just too newbie for "threading", "depth-firsting", "concurrentling" and stuff...

Comment: I will let some other devs with scrapy experience to chip in. But a simple way of making the page_parse thread safe is to avoid sharing state, so think it in a way it can be run multiple times in parallel. If you share state and modify it, then you are in trouble. For thread specific storage, you have thread local  which has a native implementation in python, and a good one is the one provided in werkzeug library

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping